# RewriteRule Not Working using RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get this

http://my.url.com/login/ or

to redirect to:

http://my.url.com/app/index.cfm?event=user.login

I am using this rewrite rule and it isn't working.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login/$
RewriteRule ^/app/index.cfm?event=user.login [NC,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of a `RewriteRule` is the pattern which matches against the URI, and you're missing that pattern. Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/?login/$ /app/index.cfm?event=user.login [NC,L]
```

If you want to externally redirect the browser, include a `R` or `R=301` (permanent) flag in the square brackets, e.g. `[NC,L,R=301]`.

Comment: I have it working in this format, but I need to make it work using RewriteCond. Is that possible?

Comment: @resonantmedia sure, add the `RewriteCond` that you have, it's extraneous and not needed but it won't break anything.